# Recursively create JSON in C# without losing the JProperties from the first iteration

Tags: c#, json

Here, I am trying to create a JSON using using Newtonsoft.Json; libraries. I came up with a function which partially does my job and when the same function is called, my previous data on the JObject is lost. I am new to this items JProperty, JObject, JArray, JToken however managed to come up with this code.

The parent is initiated in the function itself and when the function is recursively called its initiated and cleaned up again. So I added another JObject head. Making it more complicated.

```
         string statment = "(Entity.Country = 'USA' AND Entity.ShortName = 'Adele' AND (Entity.CIFNumber = '12345' OR Statement.StatementYear = '2015'))";



public static JObject ConvertToJsonObject(string text)
        {
            JObject parent = new JObject();
            string bracketContents = getWhatsInsideBrackets(text);
            parent.Add(new JProperty("operator", ReturnOperator(text)));
            parent.Add(new JProperty("rules"));
            string[] operators = splitWithOperator(bracketContents);
            List<JObject> req = new List<JObject>();

                for (int i = 0; i < splitWithOperator(bracketContents).Length; i++)
                {
                    if (!checkIfBracketsExists(operators[i].Trim()))
                    {
                        req.Add(GetEachCondition(operators, i));
                    }
                    else if (checkIfBracketsExists(operators[i]))
                    {
                        parent["rules"] = new JArray(ConvertToJsonObject(operators[i]));
                        head = parent;
                        parent["rules"] = (ConvertToJsonObject(operators[i]));
                    }
                }
            parent["rules"] = new JArray(req);
            head["rules"] = parent;
            return parent;
        }
```

I am trying to achieve this JSON output: (Only trying to achieve the key, value of DataSetCommonQuery, dont worry about the other keys on the json)

```
{
  "context": {
    "wfId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "taskId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  },
  "payLoad": {
    "DataSetCommonQuery": {
      "operator": "AND",
      "rules": [
        {
          "field": "ENTITY.CIFNumber",
          "condition": "<>",
          "value": "3123"
        },
        {
          "field": "ENTITY.Country",
          "condition": "LIKE",
          "value": "USA"
        },
        {
          "operator": "OR",
          "rules": [
            {
              "field": "ENTITY.FYEMonth",
              "condition": "=",
              "value": "May"
            },
            {
              "field": "STATEMENT.ProfitBeforeTax",
              "condition": ">=",
              "value": 123123
            },
            {
              "field": "STATEMENT.NetSales",
              "condition": "<=",
              "value": 234234
            },
            {
              "field": "STATEMENT.statementdatekey_",
              "condition": "=",
              "value": "2019-07-01 12:00:00"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "PeerType": "DEFAULT",
    "Name": "API TEST",
    "Description": "API TEST",
    "BmkPeerFormatId": "DBBmk",
    "OperationType": "Create"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you can achieve that with adding 'req' as a parameter, and pass it on every recursive call.

Comment: req do not have jproperty operator in it still. @GBursali

Comment: are you trying to save 'parent' or conditions in req

Comment: My output can be like: operator, rules[operator, rules[operator, rules[]]] and so on... In my code I an only saving the condition in the req. If I am inside the else if condition inside the for loop then we need to recursievely add the operator, rules inside existing rules[] jarray @GBursali